# In ember data model's state is not set to dirty when we modify a "belongsTo" property

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I was wondering why when we modify a belongsTo property, the model's state do not change to dirty. I wanted to check that a model is dirty before I call save request on it, but realized that the state of the model was not changing. Here is a jsBin link : http://jsbin.com/asiSipi/1/

There in the console you should be able to see that when name is changed, the state changes 
but when position is changed, the state of the model doesn't change. Is this by design? or is there some other proper way to check that a model is dirty?

Thanks,
Dee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in Ember Data right now.

https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1243

A major refactor is planned soon that should handle it, part of the excitement of using a beta release.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/10eC2NKEaFZNm2xPGteS_1BkF55l3dDv6cOCB11TtOuo/edit

Comment: Thanks, oh I will wait eagerly for this new release :)